# Sylow subgroup of a symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

> Consider the symmetric group of$S_{20}$ and it's subgroup $A_{20}$ consisting of all even permutations. Let $H$ be a $7$-Sylow subgroup of$A_{20}$. Is $H$  cyclic? And is correct the statement which says that any $7$-Sylow subgroup of $S_{20}$ is subset of $A_{20}$?

I know that order of H is 49 and H is not normal subgroup of $A_{20}$. But I don't understand whether it is cyclic or not.

Comment: If $H$ were cyclic, then there would be an element of order $49$ in $H \subset A_{20}$. Is that possible?

Comment: yes there is a element of order 49 in $A_{20}$

Comment: I know $S_3,S_4,S_5$

Comment: In $S_3$ orders of elements are 1,2,3

Comment: But we can write 20 as 7+7+1+1+1+1 +1+1

Comment: order of (12) is 2,(123) is of order 3 and (12)(345) has order 6

Comment: Yes! so if we take $x=(1234567)$ and $y=(89...14)$ then is it true that $xy=yx$? What is order of $xy$?

Comment: *I got my mistake.There don exist any element of order 49.Thank you.*

Comment: *yes since there is no element common and order of xy is 7  *

Comment: Is this $7$ssg normal in $A_{20}$?

Answer (score 2):

In $|S_{20}|$, the highest power of $7$ which divides $20!$ is $7^2$. So it is clear that the Sylow-$7$ subgroup of $S_{20}$ is of order $7^2$.

Group of order $7^2$ is either cyclic or  isomorphic to $Z_7\times Z_7$.

If it is cyclic, then $S_{20}$ will have an element of order $49$, and it should be product of disjoint cycles. Check, whether this is possible? You will reach to your answer.

Comment: yes it has a element of order 49 but what about the statement any 7-Sylow subgroup of $S_{20}$ is subset of$ A_{20}$

Comment: No! It has no element of order $49$! Consider small order groups $S_4$ and $S_5$. Can you write down orders of elements here? What standard results you are familiar with about permutations and their orders? For example, what is order of $(12)$? of $(123)$? of $(12)(345)$?

Comment: Hmm, can you say what the element of order 49 you are thinking of ?

Comment: (1234567)(891011121314)

Comment: The element $(1234567)(891011121314)$ doesn't have order 49... Maybe thinking smaller might help, what is the order of $(12)(34)$ ?

Comment: *yes you are correct.I was making mistake in calculating lcm.*

Comment: @p Groups how can we prove that there exists a 7-Sylow subgroup of $A_{20}$ which is not normal?

Answer (score -1):

For the last option
Sn has two types of subgroups: a subgroup which contains half even and half odd permutations or it contains only even permutations.